# Foursquare API - venue search

Tags: iphone, ios, foursquare

I am searching venues using Foursquare API.using below url

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=MY_TOKEN&v=20130516
```

I am getting the result in JSON format. My problem is for each venue there is a given distance. In which unit they give this unit. I am not sure about this distance is correct for me.

distace for the the place where  I am standing now should be 1m - but in the result it show `distance = 2993`

Why this happens, how can I convert it into meters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andreas has made a good example iphone project that hosted on github I tried it and it's working very well take a look at https://github.com/anka/bw_examples/tree/master/FoursquareIntegration

This may help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [**Forsquare API Venue Response Documentation**](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue):

> **location**
>
> An object containing none, some, or all of address (street address),  crossStreet,  city, state, postalCode, country, lat, lng, and distance. All fields are strings, except for lat, lng, and distance. **Distance is measured in meters.**

I performed your request in the [Foursquare API explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&v=20130516) and I found no venue with distance of 2993. You should check if you're passing good value for `ll` parameter. *It* is the location, from which 4sq will be calculating the distance. `40.7,-74` is here:

[image]

Comment: yep..sorry for that, in the question I gave the lat and long wrongly.
But in my actuall app, it giving me 2993

Comment: **That is surely not 4sq's fault.** Maybe it *should* be 3km? Make sure the latitude and longitude you're passing is correct and test them at Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Read the Detail of all parameter and implement in your URL.

Hope it works for you